# trying to draw multiple lines, "branches" for a project, only one appears on image

Tags: image, loops, go, draw

I am coding in GoLang.  I am iterating through a list of "branches" each with root and stem coordinates.  It shows that each branch is being drawn but the resulting image only contains one single branch, one of the smallest ones.  I am not sure what I am coding wrong and why it only draws one.

Here is the function where I go through branches and draw each one point by point.

It should draw each one and encode it to an image file.  Why does it only draw one?

myImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 800, 600))
white := color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 255}

```
//draw.Draw(myImage, image.Rect(0, 0, 800, 600), &image.Uniform{white}, image.ZP, draw.Src)
//black := color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 255}

myFile, err := os.Create(imagePath) // ... now lets save output image
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, branch := range branchList { // might print in arbitrary order

    /*fmt.Println("basic values: ", branch.length, branch.angle, branch.slope, " ")
    fmt.Println("coords. root:", branch.root.x, branch.root.y, "stem: ", branch.stem.x, branch.stem.y, " ")
    fmt.Println("branch roots: L:", branch.lBranchCoord.x, branch.lBranchCoord.y, "R: ", branch.rBranchCoord.x, branch.rBranchCoord.y)
    fmt.Println("branch pointers ", branch.lBranch, branch.rBranch)*/
    fmt.Println("branch values", branch)

    var x1, x2 int

    slope := (branch.stem.y - branch.root.y) / (branch.stem.x - branch.root.x)
    fmt.Println("slope: ", slope)

    if branch.root.x < branch.stem.x {
        x1 = int(branch.root.x)
        x2 = int(branch.stem.x)
    } else {
        x2 = int(branch.root.x)
        x1 = int(branch.stem.x)
    }
    if x1 < 0 {
        x1 = 0
    }
    if x2 > 800 {
        x2 = 800
    }

    y1 := branch.root.y // beware mixing up y coordiantes
    y2 := branch.stem.y

    if y1 < 0 {
        y1 = 0
    }
    if y2 > 800 {
        y2 = 800
    }
    // something is wrong with point drawing, likely having a rectangle with size 0
    if branch.stem.x != branch.root.x {
        for h := x1; h <= x2; h++ {
            // make each dot drawn 2x2 instead of 1x1
            // add a coefficient, either 1 or -1, to the values in the pixel
            // based on location
            // or, just add one to each and see what happens
            currentDot := image.Rect(h, int(float64(branch.root.y)+(float64(h-x1)*slope)),
                h+1, int(float64(branch.root.y)+(float64(h-x1)*slope))+1)

            //fmt.Println("point draw", currentDot)

            // negative coordiantes don't allow it to be drawn
            //fmt.Println("dot drawn")
            draw.Draw(myImage, currentDot, &image.Uniform{white}, image.ZP, draw.Src)
        }
    } else {
        for h := int(branch.root.y); h >= int(branch.stem.y); h-- {
            currentDot := image.Rect(int(branch.root.x), (int(branch.root.y) + h),
                int(branch.root.x), (int(branch.root.y) + h))
            //fmt.Println("dot drawn for straight line")
            draw.Draw(myImage, currentDot, &image.Uniform{white}, image.ZP, draw.Src)
        }
    }

    defer myFile.Close()
    //fmt.Println(myImage)
    png.Encode(myFile, myImage)
```

much of the stuff in the middle is just the math for drawing the branches but I am trying to figure out why I only end up with one branch.